# What is the best way to create a line of sight simulation raster?

Tags: raster, 3d, viewshed, simulation

I have been tasked to create some sight-line simulations for a powerline project. I have several (85) observation points and need to create a simulation of what the view would look like, looking from the observation points back to a proposed powerline.

I have a shapefile x,y,z of observation points, photos from observation points to proposed powerline, and a 3d drawing of powerline in autocad.

Any suggestions on the best work flow?

I have a ArcGIS licence with 3d extention, and Autocad Civil 3D.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this as a general workflow/process suggestion in [Line Of Sight](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/line-of-sight.htm)

> Only the endpoints of the input line are used to define the observer and target. Sight lines should be straight lines comprised of two vertices representing the observation point and the target location for which visibility is determined.
>
> Consider creating sight lines with the Construct Sight Lines tool if the observer location is identified by point features and the visibility targets reside in a different feature class.
>
> Output lines will be divided along visible and invisible portions of the input sight line. If only a surface is used to determine sight line visibility, the output lines will follow the surface profile. If a multipatch feature is provided when calculating line of sight, the output lines will follow the trajectory of the input sight lines.